# Batch file to open vbs from another folder

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create .bat file to start my .vbs file. Batch file is working for me only when it is located in the same folder as .vbs file. I have no idea how to solve this and after about 1 hour of googling I decided to ask you here.
My .bat file looks like this:

```
@echo off
wscript "C:\Mining\silentmode.vbs"
```

Comment: what error do you get? are you sure the silentmode.vbs exists in the path?

Comment: I wont get any error, It just wont start silentmode.vbs. I am sure that silentmode.vbs exists, because I created it there and it works perfectly untill I move .bat to another folder...

Comment: Did you call your batch file `wscript` ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your silentmode.vbs as below:

**silentmode.vbs**

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\Mining\kgtm.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

.....then you can add the option **//e:vbscript** to make sure the scripting engine will recognize your script always as a vbscript like below:

**calling.bat**

```
@echo off
wscript //e:vbscript "C:\Mining\silentmode.vbs"
```

Comment: I can't see anything which may stop running your vbs...could you please share your silentmode.vbs program here ?

Comment: Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.RUN "cmd /c c:\Mining\kgtm.bat", 0

Comment: should I think, your ultimate goal is to run kgtm.bat in silent mode that's why you are using this VBScript ?

Comment: Yep you are right, I am trying to run my miner in background so it doesnt bother me with any windows etc. It is launched by kgtm.bat, so i created that vbs to run it silently and I wanted to run this vbs by bat file located inside my startup folder. It can be done by using shortcut of this vbs file located inside my startup folder, but I am just curios why this bat doesnt work for me ...

Comment: check the EDIT and make sure to change the path in your calling batch file, if you move that to some other folder.

Comment: Ok ty I checked it again and I havent absolute adress in calling bat, now it is working. Thanks, just my fault :D

Comment: If your problem got resolved..then you can [upvote and select this as your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/about) as it'll help people to find this post useful and also will encourage users of this stack community to answer your future questions more frequently :)